# How can I bring a session variable into the AuthServiceProvider in this Laravel 8 application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a **Laravel 8** app with users, roles and permissions. I use **Microsoft Azure** for user sign-up and sign-in. I began by following **[this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tutorial-step=1)** on their website.

I use a custom middleware in `routes\web.php` to discriminate authenticated users from guests:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard', 'middleware' => ['checkSignedIn']], function() {
    Route::get('/', [DashboardContoller::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
    //More routes
});
```

I get a list of *comma-separated user permissions* specific to every user role, from a `permissions` MySQL table.

I store the `userPermissions` variable in a session like this:

```
public function storeTokens($accessToken, $user, $user_role, $user_permissions) {
 session([
  'accessToken' => $accessToken->getToken(),
  'refreshToken' => $accessToken->getRefreshToken(),
  'tokenExpires' => $accessToken->getExpires(),
  'userName' => $user->getDisplayName(),
  'firstName' => $user->getGivenName(),
  'lastName' => $user->getSurname(),
  'userRole' => $user_role,
  'userPermissions' => $user_permissions,
  'userEmail' => null !== $user->getMail() ? $user->getMail() : $user->getUserPrincipalName(),
  'userTimeZone' => $user->getMailboxSettings()->getTimeZone()
 ]);
}
```

This alows me to output the current (signed in) user's *list of permissions* in a view (the `navbar.blade.php` partial), directly *from the session*, like this:

```
@if(session('userPermissions'))
  <ul>
    @foreach (session('userPermissions') as $up)
      <li>{{ $up }}</li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
@endif
```

#### The goal

My intention (the purpose of creating `session('userPermissions')`) is to use the user's permissions in Gates. For this purpose, in `app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php` I have:

```
// More code
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
// More code

/* View Users */
Gate::define('view-users', function() {
  return in_array('view-users', session('userPermissions'));
});
```

In the base-controller (`app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php`) I have imported the Gate facade with `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate` and then, in `users.blade.php`

```
@can('view-users') 
    <h2>Users</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Role</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @if ($users)
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $user->first_name }} {{ $user->last_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->role }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
        @endif
    </table>
@endcan
```

#### The problem

Evan if the current user does have the *view-users* permission (and that is visible in the navbar), the Users table is not present and doing `dd(session('userPermissions'))` in `AuthServiceProvider.php` returns `null`.

##### Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `Policy` & `Gate` registered in `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider`.

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        User::class => UserPolicy::class,
    ];
 
    /**
     * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        // this merely maps the name of the gate
        Gate::define('view-users', [UserPolicy::class, 'index']);
    }
}
```

CLI command:

```
php artisan make:policy UserPolicy --model=User
```

Then in `class UserPolicy`, you have to implement method `index()`.

---

One can check in the controller already, before even rendering any Blade template.

For your use case ... see the examples for: [Methods Without Models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#methods-without-models) or [Guest Users](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#guest-users).

It's pointless to depend on `session()`, when the `Gate` knows `User $user` ...

Comment: Why can't the Gate work on its own? And what if I already have a `User` model, what is the CLI command then?

Comment: This is the scaffolding command when already having a `User` model; the `Policy` is the companion to it. The idea of using a framework is to use it - better not try to reinvent the wheel. I mean, telling apart logged in users and guests already has Blade directives ...

Comment: Maybe try to use the facade `Session::get('userPermissions')` instead of `session()` helper? But it's still easier to manage to put all permission-related code for a `Model` into a `Policy`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler `Session::get('userPermissions')` not worked for me in `AuthServiceProvider.php` file. any suggestion, please share. Thanks.